# Regex to replace html tags between parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I need to replace html tags placed between parenthesis. Following is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$string  = '<table><tr>Hello{<strong><br/>name<br/></strong>}</tr></table>';
echo preg_replace("/\{<.*?>\}/","",$string);
```

Required output is

```
<table><tr>Hello name</tr></table>
```

Comment: Well, that's not going to work. you have `{ SPACE <`, and your regex doesn't allow for that space...

Comment: space is not required

Comment: of course not, that's why your regex is not matching anything. you're literally saying "find a `{` followed by a `<`", and that does NOT exist in your sample text. your text is `{` followed by a space followed by a `<`.

Comment: After the edit, that code works perfectly - see https://eval.in/631694

Comment: Since the issue was caused by a typo, it is best to close this question.

Comment: It doesn't works in my code as there are many html tags under parenthesis ..let me edit the code

Comment: Why must it be regex here? Many different string methods would work just fine, culminating with a strip_tags() on the middle piece

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/423105

Comment: I need to do it by regex... lets try for best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not do this using a simple regex alone, but you can use a regex to find the paranthesis blocks as follwing

```
function process_paranthesis($match) {
  return strip_tags($match[1]);
}

$string  = '<table><tr>Hello { <strong>name</strong>}</tr></table>';
echo preg_replace_callback("/\{([^\}]*)\}/", "process_paranthesis",$string);
```

The RegEx was modified to just find all {...}-blocks and we use `preg_replace_callback()`, which calls a function that computes the string that the match is to be replaced to. The parameter $match of the callback function contains information about the match in various ways. $match[0] contains the whole text of the match and $match[1] contains the text within the first paranthesis within the match.
The function `strip_tags()` is then used within the callback function, to remove all HTML-Tags. This is a predefined function and should be used instead of reinventing the wheel.

The RegEx is constructed as following:

1. A match starts with a `{` and ends with a `}`; we need to escape it so we use `\{`...`\}`.
2. We want to process everything, but the surrounding `{` and `}`, so we put round paranthesis inside: `\{(`...`)\}` and will then get the whole content within the curly braces as $match[1] without further need to remove those curly braces by using other string functions.
3. We want to allow all characters between the `{` and `}` except for the `}` itself; we use `[^\}]`, which matches every kind of character but `}`; and we want to allow multiple of them, resulting in: `[^\}]*`

NOTE: `.*` is greedy. So, if we just use `.*` instead of `[^\}]*` we would get weird results in case there are multiple blocks of curly braces. The match would start at the first opening `{` and end at the last `}` within the string and would containing *all* blocks and everything between it. This would match like this: "Text `{in first} something between {and second one}`. And some more." -- But we want it to match like this: "Text `{in first}` something between `{and second one}`. And some more.", right?

Comment: @Stefan K. well said.

Answer (score 2):

@Diksha Try this:

```
$string  = '<table><tr><td>Hello {<strong><br/>name<br/></strong>}</td></tr></table>';


echo $str = preg_replace_callback("/\{<.*?>\}/", function($m){
    return preg_replace('/\{|\}/',"",strip_tags($m[0]));
}, $string);
```

Comment: Also good work here, Manish. Was just a bit quicker and did explain stuff. Go on with it! (upvote)